# How to inherit from python's zip but use class attrs?

Tags: python

I ran into an interesting issue... I was trying to SubClass python's `zip` type... I wanted to create a class that acted as a `zip` yet has class attrs.

At First I tried

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __init__(self):
        print('I ran')
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
        super().__init__(self.x,self.y)
```

But it seems like `zip`'s `__init__` takes nothing but `self`?

So I tried

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
        self.y = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16])

    def new(self):
        return zip.__new__(SomeClass, self.x, self.y)
```

Which works but requires I do `x=SomeClass().new()`

Finally I got to this...

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __init__(self):
        print('I ran')
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
    def __new__(self):
        self.__init__(self)
        return zip.__new__(self, self.x, self.y)
```

```
for i in SomeClass():
...     print(i)
...
I ran
I ran
(1, 1)
(2, 4)
(3, 9)
(4, 16)
```

This runs `__init__` twice... I am just curious if there is a way to circumvent this or will class attrs never exist at the time `__new__` runs?

UPDATE: This ALMOST works

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __new__(self):
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
        return super().__new__(self, self.x, self.y)
```

How ever `x` and `y` are not instance variables :(. Example

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __new__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return super().__new__(self, self.x, self.y)
```

```
>>> k=SomeClass([1,2],[3,4])
>>> k.x
[1, 2]
>>> j=SomeClass([2,2],[4,4])
>>> j.x
[2, 2]
>>> k.x
[2, 2]
```

Why is this?

Comment: `zip` as in the zip _function_? https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @NPE yep, I wanted a class that was essentially `type<zip>` but subclass it to make some custom bits...Though `zip` must not be just a function or I couldn't subclass it

Comment: @NPE oddly enough, `type(zip)` returns `<class 'type'>` as opposed to `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` like `type(len)` would, so `class Foo(zip):` seems to be possible.

Comment: `zip` is a class now because whose instances are lazy generators, rather than a function that immediately produces a list of tuples from the original lists.

Comment: Is all that code with your failed attempts really necessary in a question that asks why `__init__` is called twice? Or is the question actually "what's the correct way to do it"? I hope it's not both...

Comment: Seriously though, what is the question here? Do you want to know how to do this correctly, or do you want to know why your `__init__` is called twice? I'd rather not answer both in the same post.

Comment: I know why `__init__` is called twice. I was curious how to create the implementation without having to call twice. But it looks like I can define the class attrs within the dunder new. I thought new acted on the meta class originally and that would make `x` and `y` attrs of the meta class, I think I was wrong @Aran-Fey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the object attributes `self.x` and `self.y` in `__new__`, where `self` doesn't actually exist yet. (The thing you've so inappropriately labeled `self` is actually the class.) You're going about this backwards. First, `__new__` must *create* an object (`self`), and only *then* can you call `__init__`. (You shouldn't, though, because python will do it for you automatically.)

Now, as you've already found out, you have to have access to `x` and `y` *before* `__init__` is executed (because you have to pass them to `zip.__new__`). Because of this, it's easiest to initialize `x` and `y` directly in `__new__`. (The `__init__` then no longer serves a purpose, so it can be removed.)

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __new__(cls):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        y = [1, 4, 9, 16]

        obj = super().__new__(cls, x, y)

        obj.x = x
        obj.y = y
        return obj

    def __init__(self):
        print('I ran')
```

Demo:

```
>>> k = SomeClass()
I ran
>>> k.x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> k.y
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> list(k)
[(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]
```

Comment: I though `x` and `y` were additional values to attach to the `zip` object, not the things to zip.

Comment: Thanks, this made it clear to me. This falls into the black magic python bits for me.

Comment: @chepner Well, they're both.

Comment: If you aren't passing the iterables as arguments to `zip`, this is a clear abuse of inheritance, since you can no longer use `SomeClass` where you could use `zip`. Composition would be much more appropriate.

Comment: In my updated example? What is `self` when `__new__` is first run? The Class `SomeClass`? Thats why class attr are created?

Comment: @chepner True. I certainly don't recommend doing anything like this in real code; I just answered the question.

Comment: @bison Exactly. (You can see for yourself with `print(self)`...)

Answer (score 1):

`zip` doesn't define `__init__`. `super().__init__` actually calls `object.__init__` (since in this example, the MRO consists of just `SomeClass`, `zip`, and `object`), which expects no arguments. After calling that, you can set your own attributes.

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
```

If you don't care about cooperative inheritance, you can simplify it to

```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
```

Comment: True, I forgot that.

Comment: I was trying to return a zipped iterater of `x` and `y` on creation. This would blow up right away if you tried to pass in **kwargs.

Comment: Added `*args` to ignore accept but ignore the arguments used by `zip.__new__`.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure to understand the purpose of this, you can do it by using delegation instead of inheritance:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3,4]
        self.y = [1,4,9,16]
        self.zipp = zip(self.x, self.y)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.zipp

for x, y in SomeClass():
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Sorry yes, that works fine. This is more of a thought experiment, not an implantation thing. Your approach is what I actually have. I just went down this hole due to curiosity.

Comment: That makes sense, don't be sorry, exploring things is the best way to learn